# Do we want questions about doing your job?

Tags: discussion

I'm writing specifically about this question:

> [Is implementing a "callback" system a viable solution to high call volumes?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/195552/is-implementing-a-callback-system-a-viable-solution-to-high-call-volumes-in-a)

Traditionally this site has been for questions about general workplace issues, loosely speaking "HR" type issues that are likely to be common across many workplaces. Questions about how to organize meetings, discipline, interacting with managers, interviews, resumes, harassment, bias, dealing with colleagues, etc.

What has always been explicitly excluded is questions about your actual job. Just because you are a data scientist in your workplace doesn't mean you can ask about data science here. A car mechanic can't ask about car mechanics. An accountant can't ask about accounting.

The OP says very clearly that his job is to design call centre systems, and the question is about designing call centre systems.

Do we want questions like this? What makes this question different from the car mechanic or the accountant? Where do we want to draw the line?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO (and this is motosubatsu the TWP user speaking not the diamond - I'm not here to try and dictate site scope) the answer is the ever-popular "it depends..", specifically, it depends on what that job *is*: absolutely I'd say that questions regarding the technical means of accomplishing a task such as fixing a car, building a better mousetrap, or writing a bit software are clearly out-of-scope, and that's why some of those things have dedicated Stacks already.

But a manager or HR person asking how to go about handling a situation is a different matter - the latter is still clearly asking "how to do their job", it's just that job is in-scope here.

So if the linked question were simply asking how to implement a callback system that would easily be out of scope, but it's not. It's asking about a possible technique to manage team capacity, which (as opposed to say, managing server capacity) could be seen as more of a people management question and that puts it in more of a grey area in my book.

Initially I'd still have erred on it being off-topic, but I'll admit seeing the answers (in particular the current accepted answer) really embracing the framing of it in a team-capacity context *and* keeping the answers viable across more than just the OP's workplace has made me question that some. I'm not *entirely* convinced it's in the clear but I certainly wouldn't feel confident casting a VTC or VTRO on it.

I'm really interested to see others' input here, I know this sort of edge-case isn't likely to come up very often but that's not the same as "never".